# aws ecs: deploying django and nginx on same instance vs separate instances, behind ALB

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ecs

I am trying to deploy my production service on nginx + gunicorn + django (+RDS + Elasticache), behind AWS ALB, using ECS compose.

I am trying to use ALB for load balancing purposes, which I know that nginx can handle at the same time.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is it better to deploy WebServer(nginx) & WAS(django+gunicorn) on the same instance or different instances?
2. If it is better to deploy on different instances, then what would be the sensible proportion of numbers of instances to start with?
3. My initial thoughts are that I should use ALB for load balancing between instances that have all of the three nginx+gunicorn+django containers running. And add autoscaling group to scale those instances. If is good enough?

Thanks.

Comment: What approach did you end up following @Bossom? I'm having the exact same query!

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast Sorry I'm late to answer. I have deployed both nginx & django+gunicorn on AWS fargate. I containerized them with docker-compose command. The proportion is 1:1 but have allocated like 75% of the resources(cpu, memory) to was and 15% to Nginx with 10% left as reserve. I don't remember where I read it, but I think there was an article deploying them on difference instances are not really worth it at early stages.

Comment: So the nginx + django + gunicorn containers are run as a single task with two services(django + Nginx)

Comment: See my example ecs-params.yml https://gist.github.com/mhoonjeon/292127841dd58e9ca573b9f56a7b1c4f